# AWS Cognito on Serverless IdToken undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I'm trying to build a login system using ApiGateway, Lambda function and cognito.
I created a login API that returns the token id after a successful authentication

```
export async function login(
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
  const body: LoginRequest = JSON.parse(event.body!);
  let { email, password } = body;

  const params = {
    AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
    UserPoolId: "MY_POOL_ID",
    ClientId: "MY_CLIENT_ID",
    AuthParameters: {
      USERNAME: email,
      PASSWORD: password,
    },
  };
  const response = await cognito.adminInitiateAuth(params).promise();
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      token: response.AuthenticationResult?.IdToken,
      expires: response.AuthenticationResult?.ExpiresIn,
    }),
  };
}
```

When I try to login with email and password it give me an error if credentials are not valid and just a "{}" if they are valid.

I tried to returns response.AuthenticationResult?.Session and it works, so login works, but don't give token

That's the entire response:

```
{
    "response": {
        "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
        "Session": "AYABeByFqBoMmIHRwn6oIZvHWUMAHQABAAdTZXJ2aWNlABBDb2duaXRvVXNlclBvb2xzAAEAB2F3cy1rbXMATmFybjphd3M6a21zOmV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMTo1OTA0OTA4MDk4NTg6a2V5LzRkMmU1YTdmLTFjZDctNDljOS04ZmFjLTJkOWRjYjVjZWY5ZgC4AQIBAHiT0WsoETjA-_W2EH-EQMS-0VLOgD9a5TwyMTIsaW4GEgFrdbJMT7r-wJbAHBLfQj4IAAAAfjB8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagbzBtAgEAMGgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMgTyErKwdTA2j0_OgAgEQgDvrVyjLX7dExEs8JWLMQ4vSSsJnECrXYaPZL9HMa-utfreumVAVmGZJSXdshrrFkI7yyqSp4fxzHgyN3AIAAAAADAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADrUQD4xZFJjL5DX0QePNdc_____wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAC9fhhiRhbi2BWmcOCLfSCUx4CeDC9p-zLwuMsdtn_kofAuF4aLLINJ5eg8xjJGDJXjBgfUUVaD9-yx_hPIE2xs6A4bbKI81RoLeeprjxfgrJGHI8iZc_4D-fpwT4yC5grDZlsBUhQ_tKuamYOeV-IfIi6CYJ3W2doz6AEeELYJibyPGqnX4z6kFyrAoZj2V-7O_NJWTeYNLgNjzQEjkNmxdoANUpDVJJCTC9A4rv3r4WjknBa0SUy3_-X-l6S9oGZLs2LWMSk7j7lpj1woVg",
        "ChallengeParameters": {
            "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "MY_USERNAME",
            "userAttributes": "{\"email_verified\":\"true\",\"nickname\":\"\",\"email\":\"MY_EMAIL\"}",
            "requiredAttributes": "[\"userAttributes.nickname\"]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the exact value of `response` that you are getting? (Make sure to hide any identifying details, of course)

Comment: Yep, i did it, i just change my username and email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial challenge requires you to first set a new password, before the user is logged in. That's why the response says: `"ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED"`.

From the docs:

`[AuthenticationResult] is only returned if the caller doesn’t need to pass another challenge. If the caller does need to pass another challenge before it gets tokens, ChallengeName, ChallengeParameters, and Session are returned.`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminInitiateAuth-property

You can use the `adminRespondToAuthChallenge`-operation to set a new password:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminRespondToAuthChallenge-property

Comment: Thanks, it works!! I just added a new password via CLI